# PHP - Using cURL to store cookie session into variable / memory

Tags: php, session, cookies, curl

I'm trying to avoid cURL storing the cookie session into an actual file via "CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR".  So I created a method to catch / parse the cookies into a local variable - which is then used via "CURLOPT_COOKIE" to restore the cookie session.

I cut out the cookies via

```
preg_match_all("/^Set-cookie: (.*?);/ism", $header, $cookies);
```

To use "CURLOPT_COOKIE" we take the key=value and separate them via "; ".  However (As I'm aware), CURLOPT_COOKIE doesn't allow you throw in various flags I.e. expiration, secure flag, and so on.

**Update 1/29/2014 6:45pm**

So I think my issue actually occurs where CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION occurs.  I don't think it has to do with the flags.  It doesn't seem like the manual cookie session I have is updating when following a new location (i.e. a site has 2-3 redirects to append various cookies / session).  Which would actually make sense because utilizing CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR will directly grab / update cookies sent on header redirects.  So, I tried creating a manual redirection path while grabbing / appending the latest cookie - however this method did not work for some plain reason.

**Update 1/30/2014 4:22pm**

Almost got this figured out.  Will be updating with answer shortly.  It turns out my method works perfectly fine, it's just a matter of jumping through the manual redirected pages correctly.

**Update 1/30/2014 4:51pm**
Issue solved -- answered myself below.

Comment: But you can use curlopt header to set cookies, hmm?

Comment: @MaximKhan-Magomedov we use curlopt header to set cookies, but not to store.  cURL uses cookiejar - but that requires a fixed file on disk and that's what you want to avoid (in large scale production environments).  There's security risk with leaving cookie sessions on disk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it turns out I was actually doing this correctly and my assumptions were correct.

1. To keep the cookie session in a variable (vs. CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR).  *Make sure you have CURLOPT_HEADER and CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT enabled.*
2. CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION must be set to false.  Otherwise your cookie won't send correctly (This is where CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR does best).
3. Use preg_match_all to extract cookies. Then use strpos to find the first occurence of "=".  Some sites use encoding and include "="'s which won't work with "explode".

   ```
   $data        = curl_exec($curl);
   $header_size = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
   $header      = substr($data, 0, $header_size);

   preg_match_all("/^Set-cookie: (.*?);/ism", $header, $cookies);
   foreach( $cookies[1] as $cookie ){
       $buffer_explode = strpos($cookie, "=");
       $this->cookies[ substr($cookie,0,$buffer_explode) ] = substr($cookie,$buffer_explode+1);
   }
   ```
4. When making your next curl call, re-call the cookie var/object into CURLOPT_COOKIE.

   ```
   if( count($this->cookies) > 0 ){
       $cookieBuffer = array();
       foreach(  $this->cookies as $k=>$c ) $cookieBuffer[] = "$k=$c";
       curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, implode("; ",$cookieBuffer) );
   }
   ```

This will allow you to keep the latest variable (i.e. changing sessions) intact.

Hope this helps anyone who bumps into this issue!